# Erro de Dupla Mensagem Javascript Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

TEntei fazer um código para que eu ao alterar algo em uma div, mudava automaticamente na página em tempo real sem ter que dar refresh nem nada do género, contudo quando eu mudo o conteúdo da div se por acaso der f5, a informação aparece repetida.

```js
function Ajax(){
  var xmlHttp;
  try{    
    xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();// Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
  }
  catch (e){
    try{
      xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // Internet Explorer
    }
    catch (e){
      try{
        xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      catch (e){
        alert("No AJAX!?");
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
      document.getElementById('ReloadThis').innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
      setTimeout('Ajax()',10);
    }
  }
  xmlHttp.open("GET","index.php",true); // aqui configuramos o arquivo
  xmlHttp.send(null);
}

window.onload=function(){
  setTimeout('Ajax()',10); // aqui o tempo entre uma atualização e outra
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:#00CED1;" id="ReloadThis"></div>
teste
```

Ao executar o código se der f5 na página aparece 2x a mensagem "teste".

Queria saber se haveria alguma forma de corrigir isso.

Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Olha, o texto `teste` está fora da div#ReloadThis, por isto ele não está sendo substituído. então basta mudar o mesmo para dentro da DIV.

```js
//evitar o uso de try-cacth dentro do setTimeout.
var HttpRequest = window.XMLHttpRequest;
var requestConfig = null;

if (!HttpRequest) {
  HttpRequest = ActiveXObject;
  try {
    new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0");
    requestConfig = "MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0";
  } catch (e) { 
    try {           
      return new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
      requestConfig = "MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0";
    } catch (e) { 
      HttpRequest = null;
      return null;
    } 
  }
}

var ajax = function (url, target){
  var xmlHttp = new HttpRequest(requestConfig);     
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200){
      target.innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
      interval(url, target);
    }
  }
  xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true); // aqui configuramos o arquivo
  xmlHttp.send();
}

var interval = function (url, target) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    ajax(url, target)
  }, 10); // aqui o tempo entre uma atualização e outra
}

if (HttpRequest) {
  window.onload=function(){
    var target = document.getElementById('ReloadThis');
    interval("index.php", target);    
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:#00CED1;" id="ReloadThis">
  teste
</div>
```

Também corrigi um problema quanto a sua requisição AJAX, ela não verifica se a mesma terminou com sucesso, por isto adicionei um `status == 200`

Em todo caso, acredito que a sua solução tem outros problemas, talvez seja melhor você repensar qual conteúdo precisa ser atualizado, quando, e até se cabe usar sockets ou simplesmente procurar apenas pelos conteúdos novos. pois fazer uma requisição a cada 10ms é no minimo uma péssima ideia.

Comment: Diga me uma coisa, Porque mesmo eu colocando coisas fora da div, o site continua a atualizar coisas que não estejam dentro da div em tempo real?

Comment: o seu AJAX basicamente substituí o conteúdo de `div#ReloadThis`, acredito que o seu `index.php` tenha apenas o texto `teste`, então ao termino da requisição AJAX, ele vai atualizar o conteúdo `div#ReloadThis` com o texto `teste` e manter o texto `teste` de fora da div intacto... Se você escrever no `arquivo.php` `hello world`, então na sua pagina vai aparecer `hello world teste`.

Comment: Como faço para só atualizar a div em tempo real sem adicionar mais nada?

Comment: Gonçalo, a sua div já está sendo atualizada em tempo real, o unico motivo para aparecer o texto `teste` 2x, é pq o mesmo está inicialmente fora da div a ser atualizada.

Comment: Como corrijo isso?

Comment: Eu ao colocar uma coisa fora da div, essa coisa continua a ser atualiza em tempo real, mesmo nao estando na div e quando dou f5 aparece 2x.

Comment: Gonçalo, acredito que você tenha dois arquivos html/php, o primeiro onde está este script junto com a div e o segundo com o fragmento de pagina com o conteúdo a ser atualizado em real time... o seu script atualiza apenas o conteúdo da `div#ReloadThis` na sua primeira pagina com o conteúdo do Fragmento (segunda pagina), se ele não está se comportando desta forma, verifique se todas as suas tags html estam fechando da forma correta.

Comment: Pode me simplificar o texto, sou um pouco novato na área e não percebo alguns termos.